# Rewriting scripts "the Angular way"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Okay, I have a pretty basic site I'm working on that I'm now modifying to use a MEAN stack and thus I'm getting started with Angular. I'm using [Scotch.io's MEAN starter App](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application/) as a base to get started. So far, it's been pretty easy, I've got key components in templates and added them using ng-include.

HTML

```
    <title>First Angular Page</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Sniglet:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainStyles.css"> <!-- Stephie's styles -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/NerdCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/NerdService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="NerdController">

<!-- NAVAGATION -->
<div ng-include='"templates/navagation.html"'></div> 

<div id="site-canvas">
    <!-- HEADER -->
<div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
<div id="page-content">



    <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT / UNIQUE PAGE FRAGMENT -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</div> <!-- #page-content -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>

</div><!-- #site-canvas -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But now I've got problems, my menu.js file isn't working.  It consists pretty much entirely of add/removeClass methods using jQuery.
Here's an old Code Pen of the site I'm working on in basic HTML to demostrate how it's supposed to work.
http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/BNqJVX

```
  function toggleNav() {
if ($('#drawer').hasClass('show-nav')) {
        $('#drawer').removeClass('show-nav');
        $('#nav-icon').removeClass('open');
        $("nav li.gotsMenus").removeClass("showSub");
} else {
        $('#drawer').addClass('show-nav');
        $('#nav-icon').addClass('open');
        $("nav li.gotsMenus").removeClass("showSub");
}
}
  $('#closeButton, #site-canvas, nav li li').click(function() {
      $('#drawer').removeClass('show-nav');
      $('#nav-icon').removeClass('open');
      $("nav li.gotsMenus").removeClass("showSub");
});
```

But this doesn't work with my Angular templates. (Or at least, the click and hover functions don't.  The scroll function that auto hides the header still works mysteriously ...? So it's kinda working)

So.. where to begin? I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question but I'm new to Angular and I've been spinning my wheels for a couple of hours now.  Do I put this in a directive or controller or module or what? Do I have to rewrite this in vanilla js? And even if I did, I have other jQuery dependencies (I have an image gallery powered by Tumblr's JSON API that uses a jQuery-dependent lightbox, among other things).

If someone can just point me in the right direction I would be so grateful ;_;

Comment: All dom manipulation code should be placed in a directive

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition, when the script executes, there might not a `#menuHeader` in the DOM. You may need to add the code to the `load` callback using a delegate. So like:

```
$("#menuHeader").on('load', function () {
    // Put menu.js code here
});
```

I would put a break point and figure out what's actually in the DOM when this executes. And basically figure out what it takes to load up the DOM first, then run the script.

Comment: there is no load event for content elements and not finding a selector is hardly a race condition, it simple fails quietly

Comment: Hmm, the #menuHeader is definitely loaded, the onscroll function that toggles hidden/shown classes with jQuery is still working on that and that alone.  I moved the contents of menu.js to my "NerdController" (got the name from Scotch lol) with the same results... Only the scroll function works.